# zfs scrubbing not detecting corruption in backing store - why?

Tags: zfs, corruption

A bit of background:

I am storing VM images, my home directory, my mail, my media collection on single-primary DRBD devices built on LVM logical volumes built on two RAID0 arrays (one in each DRBD cluster node). The RAID0 is to improve access times. The two nodes in the DBRD cluster provides redundancy. I do hourly backups of my home and mail and weekly backups of the VM OSs and the media collection, all to offsite. There are occassional outages but recovery has always straightforward and without data loss. I do not need the complexity of a third node to provide quorum. This setup has worked well for a long time.

However, one area where I know I am not covered is bitrot. How do I know that that movie I haven't watched for ten years is still readable? How do I know I'm not backing up corrupted data?

So I have a script that saves all files' checksums and compares them to last time's run, reporting any differences. Obviously, much nicer would be to use some OS-provided facility to do the same kind of thing. Btrfs and ZFS spring to mind. From what I've googled, Btrfs is not mature in this area, whereas ZFS is. Also, I have more familarity with ZFS,
so ZFS is my preferred solution.

So on to the main question I want to answer: can ZFS detect corruption in its backing store?

As I don't have a spare physical machine around, I planned to experiment using a VM that has some unallocated space in its own "disk" to create a logical volume that will simulate a physical disk, give it to ZFS, create a zvol, write random data to the logical volume and check that:

1. a checksum of the zvol's contents either fails somehow (perhaps ZFS will take the zvol offline) or the checksum changes and
2. ZFS flags the corrupted backing store, albeit possibly only when I do a scrub.

Given that this test didn't work (details below), perhaps my experiment or my expectations were already flawed?

Anyway, this is what I did:

There's plenty of space in the volume group, so I can create an LV to use as the backing store for ZFS:

```
penne# vgs
  VG  #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree 
  vg0   1   3   0 wz--n- <40.46g <6.46g
penne# lvcreate --name=lvtest --size=1g vg0
  Logical volume "lvtest" created.
penne#
```

I allocate that LV to a new ZFS pool and create a zvol out of it:

```
penne# zpool create zpooltest /dev/vg0/lvtest 
penne# zfs create -V 800M zpooltest/zvoltest
penne#
```

I'm going to write 1MB of corruption about halfway through the backing store "behind ZFS's back" so to speak. How big is the backing store?

```
penne# dd if=/dev/vg0/lvtest of=/dev/null bs=1M 
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 3.24444 s, 331 MB/s
penne#
```

So halfway through is about 500000000 bytes in.

The checksum of the zvol is the thing I'm interested in. If I were using raidz, then I would expect corruption not to effect its checksum, as ZFS could work around the corruption, but when using a single disk backing store I would expect the checksum to change and scrubbing to report the disk error. So I start by looking at the zvol's checksum:

```
penne# dd if=/dev/zvol/zpooltest/zvoltest bs=1M 2>/dev/null | md5sum
ebbcd350dfe34f526c0d80b3bf2d07dd  -
penne#
```

Now I corrupt 1MB in the middle of the backing store:

```
penne# dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/vg0/lvtest seek=500000000 bs=1 count=1000000 conv=notrunc
1000000+0 records in
1000000+0 records out
1000000 bytes (1.0 MB, 977 KiB) copied, 1.27545 s, 784 kB/s
penne#
```

and recheck the zvol's checksum:

```
penne# dd if=/dev/zvol/zpooltest/zvoltest bs=1M 2>/dev/null | md5sum
ebbcd350dfe34f526c0d80b3bf2d07dd  -
penne#
```

Why did it not change?

Given that the zvol's contents appear not to have changed, then it's not surprising that a scrub does nothing:

```
penne# zpool scrub zpooltest
penne# zpool status
  pool: zpooltest
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 00:00:00 with 0 errors on Fri Mar 17 14:08:29 2023
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    zpooltest   ONLINE       0     0     0
      lvtest    ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
penne#
```

I realise blocks are being cached all over the place, so I reboot to flush everything and then recheck the zvol's checksum:

```
penne# reboot
...
penne# dd if=/dev/zvol/zpooltest/zvoltest bs=1M 2>/dev/null | md5sum
ebbcd350dfe34f526c0d80b3bf2d07dd  -
penne#
```

It's still the same! Why?

Again, given that the zvol's contents appear not to have changed, then it's not surprising that another scrub does nothing:

```
penne# zpool scrub zpooltest
penne# zpool status
  pool: zpooltest
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 00:00:00 with 0 errors on Fri Mar 17 14:09:27 2023
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    zpooltest   ONLINE       0     0     0
      lvtest    ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
penne#
```

I have seen [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103286/attempt-to-test-corruption-of-zfs-filesystem-using-dd-fails) post but there the failure to detect the corruption is explained away by the corruption being very close to the start of the backing store. But in my case I'm writing slap-bang in the middle of the backing store.

So finally, on to my question for you: what on earth is going on?

The OS is Debian 11 and ZFS is OpenZFS 2.0.3.

Thanks!

Alexis

Comment: Write some data to it first before trying to corrupt it?

Comment: Also, without redundancy, ZFS can only detect errors, it can't repair them - and even with redundancy, only if ZFS itself controls it. ZFS on top of RAID-1/5/6 whether via hardware raid, LVM, mdadm, DRBD, or whatever is almost pointless. It's no worse than any other filesystem on top of raid (better than most because of its other features like compression & snapshots & send/recv), but it can't repair bad data if it doesn't know where the redundant copies are.

Comment: @frostschutz: I just filled the zvol with zeroes, checksummed it, corrupted the backing store with 1MB from /dev/urandom, checksummed it (unchanged), rebooted, checksummed it (unchanged), scrubbed (no errors detected).

Comment: Try random data instead of zeroes. ;-)

Comment: @frostschutz: dd if=/dev/urandom of=dev/zvol/zpooltest/zvoltest said very quickly 'no space left on device', but hasn't actually exited :-) txg_sync, z_wr_iss, z_wr_int look io bound. which all makes me think you might have got it! Waiting for dd to exit so I can do the checksum+corrupt+checksum test.

Comment: @frostschutz: not sure why my zeroes didn't count as data but that was it! Thanks very much! If you turn your comment into an answer I'll accept it. scrub+status reports (cropped for comment):
...
 state: ONLINE
status: One or more devices has experienced an error resulting in data
 corruption.  ...
action: Restore the file in question if possible.  Otherwise restore the
 entire pool from backup.
   see: https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/msg/ZFS-8000-8A
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 00:00:03 with 121 errors on ...
...
errors: 121 data errors, use '-v' for a list

Comment: zeroes are just optimized away, see for example https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/blob/fa468025859f4d73ee74ece7f2f8c13ad6e5aa73/module/zfs/zio_compress.c#L138-L143 and https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/blob/fa468025859f4d73ee74ece7f2f8c13ad6e5aa73/include/sys/spa.h#L365-L373